# In nested for-loops use j= i+1 vs j = 1?

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I am having a hard time wording this question. So I will just use an example to illustrate.

Say I have the following array: A = {5,8,1,3,2,6} which is size n = 6 and indexed at A[0...5].

And I want to run a scan of some kind for comparing each value with the value adjacent to it in a left to right traversal. What is the difference between the following 2 code snippets of running a nested for-loop?

```
// snippet 1, using i to take the first and j to take whatever is next to i.
for i <- 0 to n-2 do
    for j <- i+1 to n-1 do
       // do the scanning, comparing, etc.... 


//snippet 2 using i to take the first and j to take the second. 
for i <- 0 to n-2 do
        for j <- 1 to n-1 do
           // do the scanning, comparing, etc....
```

I think that they are exactly the same and can't find any differences in the pen/paper tests I've done. Is there one?

Comment: `(i+1)..(n-1)` should produce different values than `1..(n-1)`.

Comment: @cricket_007 please elaborate. How?

Comment: There is never an instance when `i == j` in the first loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, let's walk through a run where `n = 3`

```
// snippet 1, using i to take the first and j to take whatever is next to i.
for i <- 0 to n-2 do
    for j <- i+1 to n-1 do
       // do the scanning, comparing, etc....
```

First Iteration (of outermost loop):

`i = 0` and `j = 1`

`i = 0` and `j = 2`

Second Iteration:

`i = 1` and `j = 2`

Done!

```
//snippet 2 using i to take the first and j to take the second. 
for i <- 0 to n-2 do
        for j <- 1 to n-1 do
           // do the scanning, comparing, etc....
```

First Iteration:

`i = 0` and `j = 1`

`i = 0` and `j = 2`

Second Iteration:

`i = 1` and `j = 1`

`i = 1` and `j = 2`

Notice the difference in the second iteration of snippet 2?

Comment: WOW! I can't believed I missed that. With `j <  - 1`. j starts at 1 each time the loop i restarts adding extra computations, comparisons, etc. But with `j <- i+1`. I can ensure that j does not start before i as i goes left to right! Thank you so much !!!!

Comment: @KazRodgers Correct, glad this helped.

Comment: tremendously. I was looking at two related algorithms and the value of j is the only thing that separates them. I was staring at that for a day and a half and couldn't understand the difference.

Answer (score 3):

In the first one, `j` starts to count from the next value of `i`.

Example: `i = 1, j = 2` | `i = 2, j = 3` etc.

In the second one, you are going to count from 1 regardless of the value of `i`. In other words, variable `i` has no effect on variable `j`.

Both can have their uses, but it all depends on how you use those to take the array elements.

Comment: So they are the same save for the first builds a dependancy on j to i while the second allows to j to function on it's own?

Comment: Yep pretty much it.

Answer (score 1):

Both build pairs of array elements. There are two different ideas of defining what different pairs are:

1) A pair is unique only if it includes a different element. `(A[i], A[j]) == (A[j], A[i])`

2) A pair is unique if the order of the elements is different. `(A[i], A[j]) <> (A[j], A[i])`

Additionally, snippet two also treats `(A[i], A[i])` as a pair (when `i == j`), excluding `(A[0], A[0])` and `(A[n - 1], A[n - 1])`